# How do I add assertion in JSON request in Data driven testing . I am using SOAP UI free version

Tags: json, soapui, assertion, data-driven-tests, data-driven

I am doing Data driven testing for JSON request using Soap UI free version.  I have done the parameterization using Excel as Datasource. Now I want to validate the response for each input value. Can anyone help me on how can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Groovy Scripiting for that..

for example

```
Request="""{
"qoteRef": "H0005T",
"lineusiness": "4",
 "scief": "A02",
 "pode": "CH7ND",
 "do": "1977-06-12",
 "soeOfB": "hello"
  }"""
```

Below code can read one element of json and then you can validate it

```
  def json= new JsonSlurper().parseText(Request)
  def quoteRef=json.qoteRef
```

using **JsonSlurper** inside **Groovy Script** you can proceed with validations

Comment: mona could you upvote and accept it as answer. If it helped you